# Symfony unit testing & the container

Tags: symfony, phpunit

When unit testing in Symfony 2, the controller I'm testing does not receive the service container causing the test to fail with the good old `Call to a member function get() on a non-object`

I can't use $this->forward from the testing controller as it also does not have the service container.

I found this reference but it seems as though I would be using it for the wrong reason, has anyone had any experience with this?

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/testing.html#accessing-the-container

Edit: Here is my test:

```
<?php

namespace HvH\ClientsBundle\Tests\Controller;

use HvH\ClientsBundle\Controller\ClientsController;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\HeaderBag;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class ClientsControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{

    public function testGetClientsAction()
    {

        $client = static::createClient();
        $container = $client->getContainer();
        $session = $container->get('session');
        $session->set('key', 'value');
        $session->save();

        $request = new Request;
        $request->create('/clients/123456', 'GET', array(), array(), array(), array(), '');

        $headers['X-Requested-With'] = "XMLHttpRequest";
        $request->headers->add($headers);

        /* This doesn't work */
        /*
        $controller = new Controller;
        $status = $controller->forward( 'HvHClientsBundle:Clients:getClients', array('request' => $request) );        
        */

        $clients_controller = new ClientsController();
        $status = $clients_controller->getClientsAction($request);

        $this->assertEquals(200, $status);
    }

}
```

**Here is the part of the clients controller where it fails**

```
<?php

namespace HvH\ClientsBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use HvH\APIschemaBundle\Controller\Validation;


//FOSRestBundle
use FOS\RestBundle\View\View;

class ClientsController extends Controller
{

    //Query all clients
    public function getClientsAction(Request $request)
    {
        $request_type = $request->headers->get('X-Requested-With');

        if($request_type != 'XMLHttpRequest') {
            return $this->render('HvHDashboardBundle:Dashboard:dashboard.html.twig' );          
        }

        //get any query strings
        $query_strings = $request->query->all();
        $definition = $this->get("service.handler")->definition_handler(__CLASS__, __FUNCTION__);
        //once data has been prepared 
        return $this->get('fos_rest.view_handler')->handle($view);

    }    
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to provide a minimal example of your test class, including the declaration and a method which attempts to use the container?

Comment: Thanks for the response, i've updated with example of the test and the controller that is being tested. it fails at the custom service line `$definition = $this->get("service.handler")->definition_handler(__CLASS__, __FUNCTION__);`

Comment: The reason the controller isn't getting a container is because you are attempting to instantiate and interact with it directly rather than using the $client to issue requests. I can give you an example but I'm a little confused as to why getClientsAction takes a Request as a parameter. Is the action operating on this request object or could you instead get the request using "$request = $this->get('request');" as is usually done inside a subclass of Controller?

Comment: I've taken the Request out of the params and added it in like you said. If you could give me an example that would be great!

Comment: Would it also be possible to see the route definition for the getClientsAction()?

Comment: I'm using the FOSRestBundle so routing is automatically handled by that `clients:
    type: rest
    resource: HvH\ClientsBundle\Controller\ClientsController`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the reason the controller isn't getting a container is because you are trying to instantiate and interact with it directly rather than simulating requests using the client (See the section on Functional Tests in the [Testing section](http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/testing.html) of the Symfony2 book).

You need something more like this (not sure if the route is correct):

```
public function testGetClientsAction()
{
    $client = static::createClient();

    $client->request(
        'GET', '/clients/123456', 
        array(), /* request params */ 
        array(), /* files */
        array('X-Requested-With' => "XMLHttpRequest"),
    );

    $this->assertEquals(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());  
}
```

Note also, the request() method returns a crawler instance which provides helper methods to verify the content of the response if required.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks! Looking promising but now I'm redirecting to the login, I'm sure I can figure this one out myself but if you have a link handy that would be great.

Comment: This link did the trick for the auth: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/testing/http_authentication.html